# Why can’t I import textures with the Node Wrangler add-on?

Tags: add-on, import

So I watched many tutorials on how to import textures to (Principled BSDF) but every time I do it I get this:

```
... node_wrangler\operators.py", liine 1988, in execute
   print('\nMatched Textures:')
 OSError: [WinError 233] No process on the other end of the pipe
```

[image: error message]

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

I've done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in the past, it worked. Now when I select the texture I downloaded and try to submit it I get the message that’s in the picture above.

Comment: hello, do you mean that you try a Shit Ctrl T?

Comment: I’ve did that many times and it pulled up my files, then I clicked the extracted texture folder that I downloaded, selected all and clicked (principled texture setup) and I got that error message

Comment: You've done what many times? It's not clear

Comment: Ive done ctrl shift T, it worked. Now when I select the texture I downloaded and try to submit it I get the message that’s in the picture above

Comment: Have you checked line 1988 in the operators.py file? In my Blender 3.6.2, line 1987 is the `print('\nMatched Textures:')`, and line 1988 is `texture_nodes = []` - the error message makes no sense for this line.